# Adding input values

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to add up the numbers in the row (w, x, y, z are all a part of a row) that the user gives me. I tried doing this:

```
(w, x, y, z) = input("Enter values: ").split()

row = w + x + y + z
print(row)
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Your tuple holds String values, not int.

Comment: What have you tried, what results do you get, what results do you expect?

Comment: you can sum your values like you want after converting them to either integers or floats, a pythonic way of this would be `sum(int(num) for num in input('Enter Values: ').split())`

Answer (score 1):

the values you tried adding, are string, so you need to map them into integers, and unpack them as such.

```
w, x, y, z = list(map(int, input("Enter values: ").split()))

row = w + x + y + z
print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
(w, x, y, z) = input("Enter values: ").split()

row = int(w) + int(x) + int(y) + int(z)
print(row)
```

This code should do the job. You must remember that the input function returns a string which needs to be converted into integer using the int() function.

In your code, it gets concatenated since the numbers are considered as strings.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
w, x ,y ,z = input("Enter values: ").split()
print(w + x + y + z)
```

Make sure you insert exactly 4 values or else you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this out!

```
row = input("Enter Values: ")
row = row.split()
n = 0
for num in row:
    n += int(num)
print(n)
```

This way you can have as much as values as you want!

Answer (score 0):

input returns strings not integer or float value. You need to convert the strings you get to integers.

```
w, x, y, z = input('Enter values: ').split()
row = int(w) + int(x) + int(y) + int(z)
```

or you can loop through the digits:

```
numbers = input('Enter values: ').split()
for integer in numbers:
   total += integer
```

Keep in mind that with this code if the user enters anything other than 4 digits the code will not work. You can fix that by implementing try and except blocks or checks when receiving the input like so:

```
run = True
While run:
   try:
      w, x, y, z = input('Enter values: ').split()
      row = int(w) + int(x) + int(y) + int(z)
      run = False
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      print("Please enter 4 digits seperated by a single space")
```

This will make the code loop until the user follows the instructions.